# How to read multiple AttributeValues from a SAML response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, saml

I am using Keycloak SAML, SpringBoot (Java), and I am getting a response which contains the groups that the user is in, so I have this attribute inside the SAML response:

```
<saml:Attribute Name="member" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">/ANOTHER_TEST_GROUP</saml:AttributeValue>
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">/TEST_GROUP</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
```

The attribute name is member, and he has 2 values "/ANOTHER_TEST_GROUP" and "TEST_GROUP" but in my code when I try to get "member" value like so (`data.getName() returns "member"`):

```
model.addAttribute(data.getName(), credential.getAttributeAsString(data.getName()));
```

it only get the first value which is in this case "/ANOTHER_TEST_GROUP", I was expecting to get the list of values.

Also I tried to get each individual value like so:

```
import from org.opensaml.xml.XMLObject
    XMLObject value1 = data.getAttributeValues().get(0);
    XMLObject value2 = data.getAttributeValues().get(1);
```

but after the `get(index)` method there is no useful method to get to the value it contains

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I needed like this (remember `data.getName()` returns member):

```
String[] values = credential.getAttributeAsStringArray(data.getName());
System.out.println(values[0]); // prints /ANOTHER_TEST_GROUP
System.out.println(values[1]); // prints /TEST_GROUP
```

Still I am leaving the post open if anyone knows another ways